# Correct way to pass Foreign key MVC Create action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm developing a site using MVC5 in VS2013, and I have an entity, for example:

```
Subcategory {
   ID_Subcategory int,
   ID_Category int,
   ID_Product int,
   Value string   
}
```

In the Create View it shows me DropDowns for the `foreign keys`.

Now, I reach this page/action from the `Product/Edit/5` view using this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Subcategory", new { ID_Product = Model.ProductID })">
```

and in my Create action I have this

```
    // GET: Subcategory/Create
    public ActionResult Create(int? ID_Product )
    {
        ViewBag.ID_Category = new SelectList(db.Category, "ID_Category ", "Description");
        ViewBag.ID_Product = new SelectList(db.Product, "ID_Product ", "Name");
        Categories categories = new Categories();
        categories.ProductID = (int)ID_Product ;
        return View(categories);
    }
```

And it works fine, now the Product which I came from is set in the corresponding DropDown, but the URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:54372/Subcategory/Create?ID_Product=2
```

And I think it could be a security risk, so, please tell me:

- Could it be a security risk?
- Is it to show the ID/foreign key in the URL a bad practice?
- I don't want to show the foreign ID in the URL, so, Is there a better way to pass the foreign key in this context?

thanks

Comment: Why is it a security risk? (a user could just type that into the address bar anyway)

Comment: Yes, I know a user can just type a number o whatever in the url, but I'm not saying that IT IS a security risk, I'm ASKING if COULD IT BE ONE? because I don't know

Comment: POST the id in a form then it will not display in the url. A create or edit action should not be a GET link anyway -- http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/188860/why-shouldnt-a-get-request-change-data-on-the-server.

Comment: There no problem with doing it this way.  if you change the parameter to id instead of ID_Product you can get a different look if you use the default routes `http://localhost:54372/Subcategory/Create/2`. If you have products you dont want the user to see, you should validate that in your controller before you show the view.

Comment: @Jasen, it's not a call to save a new product or an edit one, it's for to show the fields with some foreign keys defined, but yes, I didn't think about to switch from GET to POST hahaha, thanks a lot

Comment: @JamieD77, that route should really work but with one parameter, if I want to show the form to create a new product, and pass more than one parameter predefined, I think the best option is to switch to a POST